# Exception when instantiating new AmazonECSClient in a custom ConfigBuilder and in an AWS ECS container

Tags: asp.net, web-config, amazon-ecs

I am running a .Net Framework 4.8 ASP.NET web application in an AWS ECR Windows container. We need access to the resource tags for the container in a custom ConfigBuilder. The code is am running is as follows:

```
using (var ecsClient = new AmazonECSClient(awsCredentials.aws_access_key_id, awsCredentials.aws_access_key, awsCredentials.aws_session_token))
{
  var response = ecsClient.ListTagsForResource(new ListTagsForResourceRequest
  {
    ResourceArn = ContainerArn
  });

  Tags = response.Tags;
}
```

The AWS container logs produce this exception on the using statement:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Amazon.AWSConfigs' threw an exception. ---> 
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The configBuilder 'InstanceTags' failed while processing the configuration section 'appSettings'.: Error in Configuration Builder 'InstanceTags'::GetValue(FirstSettingName) (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\admin\web.config line 44) ---> 
System.Exception: Error in Configuration Builder 'InstanceTags'::GetValue(AWSProfileName) ---> 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

It is not looking for a specific setting in appSettings - just looking at the first. I am at a loss for what it could be.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.